# Earned bronze badge (Disciplined) does not appear in Achievements dialog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, achievements-dialog

I just earned the [Disciplined](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge, but do not see it under Achievements:

[image: Achievements]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all badges do appear in achievements.  Users with more than 200 reputation don't see certain bronze badges in their inbox.

There is a question on the main meta to list those bronze badges that do appear.
[Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113/236563)

Gold and Silver badges always appear.